# How can I add javascript touch spin to html when call javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have button to add new row(s) to table.
In the table row have a column with touch spin.
I want to loop through Array(Items). to make a rows. But below code make a Error Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function at function tp0

```
function showtable() {

    $('#showtable').html("");

    for(var i in Items) {

        var no = parseInt($('#tb tr').length) - 1;

        var data = "<tr role='row' class='filter' >"
         + "<td>" + no
         + "</td>"
         + "<td>"
         + "<div class='form-group'>"
         + "<input id='touch" + i + "' type='text' value='1' name='touch" + i + "' /> "
         + "<script>"
         + "function tp" + i + " () {$(\"input[name=\'touch" + i + "\']\").TouchSpin(); alert('ttt');}"
         + "</scr" + "ipt>"
         + "</div>"
         + "</td>"
         + "</tr>";

        $('#showtable').append(data);

        var method_name = "tp";
        window[method_name + i]();
    }
}
```

Have any ideas thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of adding functions like that with each row, you should just pass the row number as a variable to a predefined function:

```
function tp(index) {
    $("input[name='touch" + index + "']").TouchSpin();
    alert('ttt');
}

function showtable() {
    $('#showtable').html("");
    for (var i in Items) {
        var no = parseInt($('#tb tr').length) - 1;

        var data = "<tr role='row' class='filter' >"
            + "<td>" + no
            + "</td>"
            + "<td>"
            + "<div class='form-group'>"
            + "<input id='touch"+i+"' type='text' value='1' name='touch"+i+"' /> "
            + "</div>"
            + "</td>"
            + "</tr>";

        $('#showtable').append(data);

        tp(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: Apparently `TouchSpin` is undefined.